# Scaling images to window size while keeping relative position to each other

Tags: html, css

I want to have a container element on my site that holds 9 images ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeLFn.png)) that scale responsively to window size and keep their aspect ratio (1:1, sorry for the image) while staying in the same relative position to each other.

So far my best attempts got me to where the image height would flow out of the container element and made the window show a vertical scroll bar or the third image of a row would get pushed down to the next row.

This is what I am currently stuck with:

https://jsfiddle.net/5xdznc4e/

```
#img11 {
  position: relative;
  width: 30vmin;
  height: auto;
}

#img12 {
  position: relative;
  width: 30vmin;
  height: auto;
}

#img13 {
  position: relative;
  width: 30vmin;
  height: auto;
}
```

On resizing the window it doesn't behave nicely at all.

Comment: If it all stays quadratic all the time, then you’re probably best off using media queries to check whether you’re in portrait or landscape mode - and then set _either_ the width or height, accordingly.

Comment: flexbox is the answer, look at my code snippet in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between the image you have space because the new line.

If you use html code like this, you don't have problem:

```
<div class="container">
  <img id="img11" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img id="img12" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img id="img13" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <br>
  <img id="img21" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img id="img22" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img id="img23" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <br>
  <img id="img31" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img id="img32" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img id="img33" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <br>
</div>
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lujqcovo/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use flexbox, it's an awesome css3 feature.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container img {
  width: 28%;
  padding: 2%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img id="img11" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img12" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img13" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img21" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img22" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img23" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img31" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img32" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img33" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code this should work

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container img {
  position: relative;
  width: 32%;
  height: auto;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container img {
    width: 49%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <img id="img11" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img12" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img13" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  
  <img id="img21" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img22" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img23" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  
  <img id="img31" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img32" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img33" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Remove those BR tags and add the below class and rule.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container wdth">
  <img id="img11" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img12" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img13" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img21" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img22" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img23" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img31" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img32" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img id="img33" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wdth{
  max-width:400px
}
```